# How to use multi cURL with import.io

Tags: curl, curl-multi, import.io

I have multiple PHP files and each one stores a value to a database using the import.io service and curl. Is there a way to use multi curl and merge them in one file? Because I am running a lot of cron jobs for each file and I would like to simplify things - run a single file that does the data import and stores each data feed to a specific ID in MySQL.

```
<?php
function query() {

$url = "https://api.import.io/store/data/path-to-value";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode(array("input" => $input)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return json_decode($result);
}

$result = query();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "database";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(count($result->results) > 0) {
$length = 6;
foreach ($result->results as $index => $row) {

$sql = "UPDATE Table-name SET Column-name='" .substr($row->row-name, 0, $length). "' WHERE ID=16";

}

} else {
$sql = "UPDATE Table-name SET Column-name='-' WHERE ID=16";
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "ID16 updated successfully!";
} else {
echo "Error updating ID16: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to make the process faster:

- Use `curl_multi_init` to run requests in parallel

OR

- Use the same cURL handler (`$ch`) instead of closing it every time you make a request. In this case you save the handshakes speeding up the process for many requests.

Comment: I was thinking of those ideas but I don't know how to merge the scripts in order to use curl_multi_init - I discovered also that some curl requests take longer than others and I don't know how to allow enough time for each one.